# Calling jquery event handler from knockout compoenent

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a global event handler for all my buttons that looks like this:

```
$(".btn").mouseup(function () {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Just something simple to make sure that buttons don't stay focused after the user clicks it.

However, this does not work for knockout-made components.

I don't think it would make sense to make a global event handler like the above only to make another one in my viewmode since that introduces redundant code. Is there any way to let the above event handler handle my knockout buttons as well as all the rest?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the answer:

To make something like this work, one would have to delegate the handling of the event to a static container that knockout never touches such as `document`.

So to make a global event that will work for all, you would do something like:

```
$(document).on('mouseup', '.btn', function () {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

In my case.